cp 'same file' error when using -L with find and xarg
I'm trying to replace symlinks in my current directory with the files they point to.  I thought I understood 'cp' and the '-L' argument, but apparently not.
Here's the command I am using
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type l -regex ".*\(pdf\|odp\)" | xargs readlink -f | xargs cp -Lf -t .

Here's the error I get
cp: '/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.pdf' and './file.pdf' are the same file

What am I missing

Please always mention your operating system when posting questions. There are many implementations of the various commands, even the basic ones like cp and they can have different meanings for the same command line switches.

You're tasking cp to copy the target of the link to the current directory. If the target has the same name as the link, the copy and the original are the same file, so it doesn't do the copy. The -f option doesn't overcome this error.

You need to remove the symlink before copying the target in its place. You'll need to save the target path in a variable to do this.

Surely you don't want to physically copy all the files? If they are on the same file system, you would remove the symbolic link, create a hard link in its place, then unlink the original filename (maybe after you verify the files have two hard links so won't lose the data).

Actually I do want to copy the files, they are the starting point for revising them for a new term.  (And please don't call me Shirley). ;)

-L is mostly only useful for recursive copies, as following symlinks is the default otherwise.
And you're passing the target of the link to cp anyway so if anything that's not following symlinks for the target that would want so that cp does not realise it's the same file, but -L/-H/-P are only concerned about symlinks in the source.
Here you're running into the extra unrelated check that GNU cp makes for source and target files being the same. With -f and the target being a symlink, you could argue there's a bug here as the source is going to be unaffected and the target will be a different file.
You could use busybox cp instead, which doesn't do that check and also supports that GNU -t extension.
find . ! -name . -prune '(' -name '*.odp' -o -name '*.pdf' ')' -type l \
  -exec busybox cp -ft . {} +

No need for readlink, which anyway with your approach wouldn't work for filenames with spaces, quotes or backslashes.
If using GNU find, you could add a -xtype f to only copy the files that eventually resolve to regular files, or if using zsh, you'd just do:
busybox cp -f ./*.(odp|pdf)(@-.) .

zsh also has builtin support for readlink -f (or its realpath standard equivalent) with its :P modifier, so:
busybox cp -f ./*.(odp|pdf)(@-.:P) .

Would copy the files using their realpath target, which by the way may have different file names and not necessarily end in .odp or .pdf and could even overwrite unrelated files in the current working directory, like if you have a file.pdf -> path/to/file.pdf.old where that would end up doing cp -f ./file.pdf.old . and overwrite the file.pdf.old here.
